# Make [admanager] a synonym of [google-ad-manager]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[admanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admanager) has 24 questions, [google-ad-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-ad-manager) has about a hundred.

All of these questions are about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ad_Manager

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed; the [admanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admanager) tag was indeed being used as a synonym for [google-ad-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-ad-manager) on all questions that had it.

Blew away a couple of old useless questions while I was in the process of confirming, and then merged the tags and created a synonym.

These easy retag requests are nice for a change. :-)